# Javascript function setTimeout DOM is not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have created to function to display error and fade after 3s.Error message get displayed and it won't disappear.

```
 function showError(error){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
    errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
    //  placing a text with in div
    errorDiv.append(document.createTextNode(error));
    //placement of error
    const card = document.querySelector('.card');
    const heading = card.firstChild;
    card.insertBefore(errorDiv,heading);
  }
  ,3000);
}
```

I know I could declare another function to fadeout the error instead of  calling setTimeout in the above mentioned  showError function.
Please Can someone can give a proper explanation why the setTimout do not work?

Comment: What part of this code is supposed to make the message fade out?

Comment: It looks like it waits 3 seconds and then shows the  message. It never fades it out.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not hiding it anywhere in the code. It just shows errors after 3s with that line `card.insertBefore(errorDiv,heading)`.

Comment: What do you mean?  Does it add the error element or not?  Is the issue that it doesn't go away?  there is no logic shown that would even attempt to make it disapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking such a horrible question.  I thought setTimout function executing its content for the given time period.
I didn't realize what was its intended for but now I know.

The setTimeout()  sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You're waiting 3 seconds to show the message, not to remove it.

Show the message immediately, then use `setTimeout()` to remove it.

```js
function showError(error) {
  const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
  errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
  errorDiv.append(document.createTextNode(error));
  const card = document.querySelector('.card');
  card.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', errorDiv);
  // remove after 3 seconds
  setTimeout(() => {
    errorDiv.remove();
  }, 3000);
}
```